# NoBeanDefFoundException with Mock ViewModel, testing with Koin, Espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing, androidx, koin

I have been trying to get a simple `Espresso` unit test work with `Koin` as DI tool. Here are the dependencies that I am using in `build.gradle`

```
    // testing with Koin
    // because of this
    // https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin/pull/604/commits/69391bc378bbb9007b9d82c46537e7d753be7ea3
    androidTestImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-android:3.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation ("org.koin:koin-test:$koin_version") {
        exclude group: 'org.mockito'
    }

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    // stuff like ActivityTestRule
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.2.0'
    // AndroidJUnit4
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    // test runner
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
```

my `ViewModel` declaration

```
open class LoginViewModel(private val apiService: MockApiService) : ViewModel() {
..
..
}
```

here is how its injected in Activity

```
private val loginViewModel: LoginViewModel by viewModel()
```

my custom `TestRunner` in order to have custom `TestApplication` instantiated

```
class MyTestRunner : AndroidJUnitRunner() {
    override fun newApplication(cl: ClassLoader?, className: String?, context: Context?): Application {
        return super.newApplication(cl, TestApplication::class.java.name, context)
    }
}
```

`TestApplication` class. I have verified that this test class gets initialised when test is invoked

```
class TestApplication : Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        startKoin {
            androidLogger()
            androidContext(this@TestApplication)
            modules(emptyList())
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my actual `androidTest`. This fails as soon as activity is started with `NoBeanDefFoundException`

> No definition found for 'com.abhishek.mvvmdemo.onboarding.LoginViewModel' has been found.

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
@LargeTest
class LoginActivityTest : KoinTest {
    private lateinit var loginViewModel: LoginViewModel

    @get:Rule
    val activityRule = ActivityTestRule(LoginActivity::class.java)

    @Before
    fun beforeTest() {
        loginViewModel = declareMock()
        loadKoinModules(
            module {
//                single { ApiModule.providesApiService() }
                viewModel { loginViewModel }
            }
        )
    }

    @Test
    fun testProgress() {
        activityRule.launchActivity(null)
        onView(withId(R.id.emailEt))
            .perform(ViewActions.typeText("abhishek"))
    }

    @After
    fun afterTest() {
        stopKoin()
    }
}
```

I have tried a lot of permutation and combinations but got no luck. I also happen to have following configuration in my gradle

```
testOptions {
        animationsDisabled = true
    }

    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst 'mockito-extensions/org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker'
    }
```

and

```
testInstrumentationRunner "com.abhishek.mvvmdemo.MyTestRunner"
```

## **TL;DR**

Here is a [github sample](https://github.com/abhishekBansal/mvvm-architecture-demo) that reproduces the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening here is that the `ActivityTestRule` launches the activity before your `@Before` method, so the mock has no chance to be initialized.

From the official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/rule/ActivityTestRule),

> This rule provides functional testing of a single Activity. When
>   launchActivity is set to true in the constructor, the Activity under
>   test will be launched before each test annotated with Test and before
>   methods annotated with Before, and it will be terminated after the
>   test is completed and methods annotated with After are finished.

You should instead specify that you do not want to launch the activity automatically, by using this [constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/rule/ActivityTestRule.html#ActivityTestRule(java.lang.Class%3CT%3E,%20boolean,%20boolean))

```
ActivityTestRule (Class<T> activityClass, 
                boolean initialTouchMode, 
                boolean launchActivity)
```

Then in your test method you can launch your activity manually by

```
activityRule.launchActivity(null)
```

Also, you may want to check out https://mockk.io/ for mocking. You will not have to declare your classes as `open`.